# Purify html string in Yii

Tags: php, yii, xss, htmlpurifier

I'm trying purify a string to prevent a XSS atack, but if a string don't have a script tag but have html attributs, the string isn't purify.

**Example:**

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/54f74"onmouseover%3d"alert(1)"style%3d"position%3aabsolute%3bwidth%3a100%25%3bheight%3a100%25%3btop%3a0%3bleft%3a0%3b"54f74';
$purifier = new CHtmlPurifier();
var_dump(
    $str,
    $purifier->purify($str)
);
```

**result:**

```
string 'http://www.example.com/54f74"onmouseover%3d"alert(1)"style%3d"position%3aabsolute%3bwidth%3a100%25%3bheight%3a100%25%3btop%3a0%3bleft%3a0%3b"54f74' (length=145)
string 'http://www.example.com/54f74"onmouseover%3d"alert(1)"style%3d"position%3aabsolute%3bwidth%3a100%25%3bheight%3a100%25%3btop%3a0%3bleft%3a0%3b"54f74' (length=145)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because that string is valid XSS-free HTML. To purify it if you were planning to use it in an attribute, you could use HTML Purifier's internal `AttrDef` classes to manually purify it. For URLs, you probably want `HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI`:

```
$def = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI();
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::default();
$context = new HTMLPurifier_Context();
$pure_url = $def->validate($your_url, $config, $context);
```

Comment: I noticed that purify makes encode special characters. There some wood I not do?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.